# iphone Core Data - What type of proprty for a float?

Tags: iphone, core-data, floating-point

what type should my property be to work properly with core data float variables.

For example in order to get my class to work with int32 in core data i had to create NSNumber in my class. how about the float variables in core data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be an NSNumber as well.

Answer (score 0):

NSNumber should do nicely.